# Trouble finding non-unique index entries in zooreg time series

Tags: r, zoo

I have several years of data that I'm trying to work into a zoo object [(.csv at Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vg8w8pt16e0v3xs/AABKtWqDkPu9JVKpwBXO36VOa?dl=0). I'm given an error once the data is coerced into a zoo object. I cannot find any duplicated in the index.

```
df <- read.csv(choose.files(default = "", caption = "Select data source", multi = FALSE), na.strings="*")
df <- read.zoo(df, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", regular = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, index.column = 1)
Warning message:
In zoo(rval3, ix) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I've tried:

```
sum(duplicated(df$NST_DATI))
```

But the result is 0.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Including a link to your actual data was brilliant. +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `read.zoo(...)` incorrectly. According to the documentation:

> To process the index, read.zoo calls FUN with the index as the first
>   argument. If FUN is not specified then if there are multiple index
>   columns they are pasted together with a space between each. Using the
>   index column or pasted index column: 1. If tz is specified then the
>   index column is converted to POSIXct. 2. If format is specified then
>   the index column is converted to Date. 3. Otherwise, a heuristic
>   attempts to decide among "numeric", "Date" and "POSIXct". If format
>   and/or tz is specified then they are passed to the conversion function
>   as well.

You are specifying `format=...` so `read.zoo(...)` converts everything to Date, not POSIXct. Obviously, there are many, many duplicated dates.

Simplistically, the correct solution is to use:

```
df <- read.zoo(df, FUN=as.POSIXct, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
# Error in read.zoo(df, FUN = as.POSIXct, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") : 
#   index has bad entries at data rows: 507 9243 18147 26883 35619 44355
```

but as you can see this does not work either. Here the problem is much more subtle. The index is converted using `POSIXct`, but in the system time zone (which on my system is US Eastern). The referenced rows have timestamps that coincide with the changeover from Standard to DST, so these times *do not exist* in the US Eastern timezone. If you use:

```
df <- read.zoo(df, FUN=as.POSIXct, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")
```

the data imports correctly.

**EDIT**:

As @G.Grothendieck points out, this would also work, and is simpler:

```
df <- read.zoo(df, tz="UTC")
```

You should set `tz` to whatever timezome is appropriate for the dataset.

Comment: If `tz` is specified it will know that POSIXct is wanted (as the alternatives it considers don't use time zones) so `FUN` could be omittted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You have no idea how much this is appreciated. I haven't implemented your solution **just** yet, but I will within the next few days. I'll let you know how it turns out.

I love this community.