# error read.zoo() without duplicates and using the correct format and time zone

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I am trying to gain the following result in this post: [Aggregating hourly data into daily aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200437/aggregating-hourly-data-into-daily-aggregates)

However, i got stuck in reading the zoo file. I have run the following script on the attached data file

[tab delimited file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4tpqz5lj5hclxn/Plot6_Temp.txt?raw=1)

```
#reading datafile
Temp6 <- read.table("Plot6_Temp.txt", header = TRUE, sep="\t")

anyDuplicated(Temp6$Time)
Temp6_corr <- Temp6[-c(3495),]

z <- read.zoo(Temp6_corr, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", format ="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="Europe/London")
```

I have tried for UTC time zone (as data is mostly stored in this format), as well as the suggested as.chron() function here:

[Error in read.zoo index has bad entry at data row 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537501/error-in-read-zoo-index-has-bad-entry-at-data-row-2/35540680)

And the correct format and utz settings as mentioned here:

[Trouble finding non-unique index entries in zooreg time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361500/trouble-finding-non-unique-index-entries-in-zooreg-time-series)

However, i get either the error:
"index has bad entry at data row 3900", 
when running it with

tz = "Europe/London"

or the error: 
"some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique"
when running it with

tz = "UTC"

however running:

```
Temp6[c("3899", "3900", "3901"),]
```

Does not show any deviant values or strange entries for row 3900.

Adding: index.column = 1 , does not provide a solution either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks to Joris Meys in the 'aggregate' blog post (first link) I have worked around it, however, for future projects I would still be interested in why these errors show up in the read.zoo() conversion.